# Unsupported Samsung Galaxy S8+– dream2lteks

Tags: android, android-manifest

This device showed as unsupported in GooglePlay console.
[Unsupported Galaxy S8+](http://joxi.ru/Rmz5qZWt9pBxrO)

But other Galaxy S8+ showed as [Supported Galaxy S8+](http://joxi.ru/DmB4NPpCV0GRAP)

AndroidManifest.xml has next compatible-screens

```
<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="420" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="420"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480"/>    
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="640" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Maybe someone faced with this problem?

Comment: why do you need to specify `compatible-screens` at all? do you really not want to support all screen sizes and densities? If you want to support all screens, just remove that xml tag altogether, or consider switching to the `supports-screens` tag instead

Comment: I have a four apk for different screen (small/medium/large/tablet), so I need to specify <compatible-screens> for each apk.

I tried to use supports-screens but GooglePlay console show so many errors with existing apk.

Comment: see my answer then

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `compatible-screens` which requires you to specify the actual density of the device, you can switch to using [`supports-screens`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) which does not.

So, if you have 4 apks each targeting a different form-factor, you can have these options in your 4 manifests (notice the `anyDensity` is set to `true`):

```
<supports-screens
   android:anyDensity="true"
   android:xlargeScreens="true"
   android:largeScreens="false"
   android:normalScreens="false"
   android:smallScreens="false"/>

<supports-screens
   android:anyDensity="true"
   android:xlargeScreens="false"
   android:largeScreens="true"
   android:normalScreens="false"
   android:smallScreens="false"/>

<supports-screens
   android:anyDensity="true"
   android:xlargeScreens="false"
   android:largeScreens="false"
   android:normalScreens="true"
   android:smallScreens="false"/>

<supports-screens
   android:anyDensity="true"
   android:xlargeScreens="false"
   android:largeScreens="false"
   android:normalScreens="false"
   android:smallScreens="true"/>
```

If you want more fine-grained control on the exact buckets each apk will server, there are also the following attributes you can use:

```
android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"
```